# How to unnest (unlevel) unnecessary nested list without changing its shape? (Python)

Tags: python, nested-lists

This is quite different what I found in many threads - I don't mean to make list flat but unnest levels as follows:

`[[[3, 3]]]` should be `[3, 3]`

`[[[3, 4], [3, 3]]]` should be `[[3, 4], [3, 3]]` but not `[3, 4], [3, 3]` nor `[3, 4, 3, 3]` because this changes the structure completely.

Basically, I wanted to reduce levels to get the same `len(a_list)` in first and second iteration before loop break. But my idea is somewhat wrong:

This code works for anything but `[[3], [4]]`. Dunno what's wrong today because it worked yesterday. Need some help to correct this function. Now it returns [3] but should be unchanged.

```
# Unlevel list - reduce unnecessary nesting without changing nested lists structure
def unlevelList(l):
    if len(l) > 0 and isinstance(l, list):
        done = True
        while done == True:
            if isinstance(l[0], list):
                if len(l) == len(l[0]):
                    l = l[0]
                else:
                    l = l[0]
                    done = False
            else:
                done = False
        return l
    else:
        return l
```

Comment: I believe your implementation will run into problems if your sublists are of different sizes i.e. if your data structure isn't rectangular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this with recursion: if the object is a list of length 1, strip off the outer layer; then, recursively unlevel all of its children.

```
def unlevel(obj):
    while isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) == 1:
        obj = obj[0]
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [unlevel(item) for item in obj]
    else:
        return obj

test_cases = [
    [[[3, 3]]],
    [[[3, 4], [3, 3]]],
    [[3], [4]],
    [[[3]]],
    [[[3], [3, 3]]]
]

for x in test_cases:
    print("When {} is unleveled, it becomes {}".format(x, unlevel(x)))
```

Result:

```
When [[[3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [3, 3]
When [[[3, 4], [3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [[3, 4], [3, 3]]
When [[3], [4]] is unleveled, it becomes [3, 4]
When [[[3]]] is unleveled, it becomes 3
When [[[3], [3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [3, [3, 3]]
```

---

Edit: reading your question again, I think perhaps you want `[[3], [4]]` to remain `[[3], [4]]`. If that is the case, then I interpret the requirements to be "only strip off excess brackets from the top layer; leave inner one-element lists unaffected". In which case you don't need recursion. Just strip off the top list until you can't any more, then return it.

```
def unlevel(obj):
    while isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) == 1:
        obj = obj[0]
    return obj

test_cases = [
    [[[3, 3]]],
    [[[3, 4], [3, 3]]],
    [[3], [4]],
    [[[3]]],
    [[[3], [3, 3]]]
]

for x in test_cases:
    print("When {} is unleveled, it becomes {}".format(x, unlevel(x)))
```

Result:

```
When [[[3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [3, 3]
When [[[3, 4], [3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [[3, 4], [3, 3]]
When [[3], [4]] is unleveled, it becomes [[3], [4]]
When [[[3]]] is unleveled, it becomes 3
When [[[3], [3, 3]]] is unleveled, it becomes [[3], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: This incorrectly unlevels `[[[3], [3, 3]]]` into `[3, [3, 3]]`, where I believe `[[3], [3, 3]]` is expected.

Comment: @blhsing I think you are correct. I have added an additional approach.

Comment: Honestly not bad. This "excess brackets only" was what I looking for. Thanks for 2 versions.

Comment: This is done but I can't change `[[[[4]]]]` to get a list always. So instead `4` want to have `[4]`.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could change the final line to `return obj if isinstance(obj, list) else [obj]`. Nathan's answer also ensures that the result is a list.

Answer (score 2):

Id recommend a recursive solution as well

```
def unnest(l):
    if isinstance(l, list) and len(l) == 1 and isinstance(l[0], list):
        return unnest(l[0])
    return l
```

Some test cases

```
test_cases = [
    [[[3], [3, 3]]],
    [[[3, 3]]],
    [[[3, 4], [3, 3]]],
    [[3], [4]],
    [[[3]]]
]

for i in test_cases:
    print(unnest(i))
```

gives

```
[[3], [3, 3]]
[3, 3]
[[3, 4], [3, 3]]
[[3], [4]]
[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to do exactly what you want. Maintain the lists as lists(but flat).

```
import itertools

a = [[[[1, 2]]], [[2, 3, 4, 5]], [[[[[[134, 56]]]]]], 9, 8, 0]
res = []

for element in a:
  if isinstance(element, list):
    while len(element) == 1:
      element = list(itertools.chain(*element))
    res.append(element)
  else:
    res.append(element)

print(res)
```

With the result `res` being `[[1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5], [134, 56], 9, 8, 0]`

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (not to take out internal nests) but it's useful as well.